# Supporting kUTTypeToDoItem with UIActivityViewController in iOS8

Tags: ios, uikit, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller, uti

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to share a piece of text from my app with other apps (that are using iOS8 share extensions). The code for exporting from my app is very simple:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[shareString] applicationActivities:nil];

// Set a completion handler to handle what the UIActivityViewController returns
[activityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError * error){

    NSLog(@"activityViewController - completionHandler");
}];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

With this, I'm just sharing an NSString, and it works fine. I would like to be able to support custom UTI types. In particular, with iOS8 there is also a new UTI type, kUTTypeToDoItem. If possible, I would like to be able to export the data out of my app packaged as a ToDo item, so that apps like Things or Reminders can accept them and populate a new item in their own data stores.

I'm not sure if this is possible; if so, how to go about it. Is there a reference for how to package your own data into an object that can conform to such a protocol? I'm guessing that to support a ToDo item, you would need fields like "reminder date/time", "note" etc. I can provide these from my app, but I'm not sure how to add them into a `UIActivityViewController` such that they will be processed by other todo-list apps.